# How to link two arrows in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following little graphic and want to link the two arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item durch Einigung und Abtretung des Herausgabeanspruchs

\begin{tikzpicture}[text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.3ex]
  \node (v) {V};
  \node (e) [right= of v] {E};
  \node (d) [below= of e] {D};
  \node [right,xshift=.5cm,label=right:Dritter (Amazon)] at (d.west) {};
  \node [below] at (d.south) {$\blacksquare$};
  \path (v) edge[->] (e);
  \path (v) edge[dashed,->] (d);
  \path (e) edge[dashed,->] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe pic]

I need to symbolize the move of the dashed arrow, but how to do it?

BTW, is there a better way for the placement of the label node of node d (Amazon ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `to` path for example, like this:

```
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] ($(v)!.6!(d)$) to[bend left] ($(e)!.5!(d)$);
```

to connect the point at `.6` the length from node `(v)` to node `(d)` to the point at `.5` from node `(e)` to node `(d)`. You need to add the `calc` library to calculate the required ratios.

Another option is to load `\usetikzlibrary{angles}` and use this

```
\draw pic[draw, <-, angle radius=1cm] {angle=e--d--v};
```

to draw the arc similar to the first method.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item durch Einigung und Abtretung des Herausgabeanspruchs

\begin{tikzpicture}[text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.3ex]
  \node (v) {V};
  \node (e) [right= of v] {E};
  \node (d) [below= of e] {D};
  \node [right,xshift=.5cm,label=right:Dritter (Amazon)] at (d.west) {};
  \node [below] at (d.south) {$\blacksquare$};
  \path (v) edge[->] (e);
  \path (v) edge[dashed,->] (d);
  \path (e) edge[dashed,->] (d);
  \draw[->,shorten >=1pt] ($(v)!.6!(d)$) to[bend left] ($(e)!.5!(d)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I went with `\draw pic[draw, <-, angle radius=.8cm,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt,very thick,color=black!80] {angle=e--d--v};`; worked like a charmand I learned somethig new about TikZ, thanks! ;-)